# Aure Endpoint monitoring for website getting error "could not update the settings for endpoint monitoring"

Tags: azure

I am hosting on Azure Standard S1 Plan.
When I tried to setup endpoint monitoring for homepage of my site.

(at current portal, manage-->monitoring-->End point)

On clicking the save button at the bottom I am getting this error

Updating the configuration for web app failed
could not update the settings for endpoint monitoring
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJ29x.gif)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLh0W.gif)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please show us details on your problem regarding your azure project and the entire error message.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the scenario it is working properly. You need to make sure you give a proper URL that you can actually see on your browser

Just start by giving the website URL https://.azurewebsites.net/

[image]

Please provide a screenshot and also press F12 and get the error you see on Console if it happens to you again.

Thanks and Welcome to SO. A Couple of screenshots on your questions helps us alot in answering your questions quickly.

Comment: It just would not work in my case. I tried monitoring 1 endpoint with one test location. Still the same error. I am attaching my screen shot as well.